# Has Saber, Arcuied, Shiki or any other Typemoon characters ever canonically meet one other within their respective story?

Tags: fate-series, nasuverse, type-moon, all-around-type-moon

In All Around Type-Moon spin-off manga. It was mentioned that Saber from Fate/Stay Night, Arcuied from Tsukihime and Shiki from Kara no Kyoukai are the three main heroine of Nasuverse and they meet each other there, saying long time no see.

Have these three ever met before in their original story? Or if they weren't, is there any character, preferably the main characters, from their representative story meet each other?

---

And by original story I mean in Fate/Stay Night visual novel, its prequel Fate/Zero and its sequel, Fate/Hollow Ataraxia, Tsukihime visual novel and Kara no Kyoukai light novel.

Comment: Aozaki Touko canonically exists in both Kara no Kyoukai and Tsukihime, though I don't believe she actually appears in Tsukihime (we just hear about her through Aoko). The main Fate works don't have any overlap with KnK/Tsukihime that I'm aware of.

Comment: @senshin Touko is mentioned in Fate works but more prominently reference in the Havens Feel True End

Comment: You could argue Arcueid met EMIYA (well, sort of) in Fate/EXTRA if you were to select him as your servant and go through the Rani route, she gets summoned as a Berserker though, so there's little she would remember about this instance (FGO has made clear that Servants keep their memories from HGW that took place in the Moon Cell unlike normal HGW)

Comment: There was Garden of Order, a crossover event in Fate/Grand Order in which Shiki is a servant though I'm not sure how canon F/GO really is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they have but not in a way which lines up their individual timelines. this is because i would suggest they have met in [Ahnenerbe](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Ahnenerbe)

> Ahnenerbe is a shop with two entrances located beside a cinema, and it exists in multiple locations, often appearing and disappearing. **It also appears as a regular shop within different series, such as in Fate, where it is located near the large bridge in Fuyuki City.** There is a rumor that people who under normal circumstances cannot meet each other are able to meet inside. It is the frontier where the worlds of Tsukihime and Kara no Kyoukai meet. Shiki Tohno and Shiki Ryougi, and Arcueid Brunestud and Touko Aozaki, are all related people that cannot be inserted together in a formal time axis without causing inconsistencies in the workings of either world. **When characters from different works meet in this shop, any time discrepancies are eliminated so that they can appear at the age that they were introduced.**

aside from the location in Fuyuki i recall that is it also located in Misaki Town (location of *Tsukihime*) as

> The menu includes strawberry pie recommended to Akira Seo by Fake Shiki for its fine taste

i recall in the Tsukihime PLUS-DISC story, "Alliance of Illusionary Eyes" this recommendation was the Fake Shiki taking Akira Seo to a coffee shop and having the pie.

Now as for when they could have entered Ahnenerbe. while there are times in *Kara no Kyoukai* and *Tsukihime* where Ryougi Shiki and Arcuied could just be wondering about and have entered off-screen, in regards to Saber's at the very most i don't recall her entering the coffee shop during her date with Shirou in the Fate Route of *Fate/Stay Night* and she she didn't go on any "dates" with Irisviel during *Fate/Zero*. haven't not played *Fate/Hollow Ataraxia* but understanding how it's played it's possible she may have went there off-screen during then since the Servants in *Fate/Hollow Ataraxia* have a bit more freedom around Fuyuki (ie. Lancer going fishing)

Answer (score 1):

The only other time I can recall all three meeting would be the end of Carnival Phantasm, which is entirely non-canonical, but featured every Nasuverse character showing up for the after party.

Answer (score 0):

I've played through Tsukihime and most Fate games and have never seen (or never noticed) Saber appearing in Tsukihime or Arcuied in the Fate games, even though according to the [Tsukihime page](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Tsukihime) on the TYPE-MOON wiki "the end of the story of Tsukihime takes place around the beginning of Fate/stay night". (On a side note, there is almost no chance of Saber appearing in Tsukihime as Fate/stay was released 4 years after the release of Tsukihime (2000 & 2004).

As for Kara no Kyoukai I've only watched the anime adaptations, but the chance of either Saber or Arcuied appearing is even lower as in the previous case as this light novel was released in 1998-1999 and according to the [Kara no Kyoukai page](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Kara_no_Kyoukai) on the wiki mentioned above the whole setting takes places in a parallel universe to TYPE-MOON's other series.